# I recently added a /ping latency command, but now some commands don't work and I don't get errors

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I recently added a /ping latency command, but now some commands don't work and I don't get errors.

this is the ping command code is bellow.

```
import { Client, Message, MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageSelectMenu } from'discord.js';
const db = require('quick.db')
const moment = require('moment')
import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";


    export default{
        name: 'ping',
        description: "Fetches the client latency",
        category: "Utilities",
    
        slash: 'both',
        testonly: true,
    
    
        /** 
         * @param {Client} client 
         * @param {Message} message 
         * @param {String[]} args 
         */
    
         callback: async({ client, message, interaction, args }) => {
            if (message) {
                const msg = await message.channel.send ({content: `>  Pinging..`})
                msg.edit({content: `>  Pong! Latency: **${client.ws.ping}ms**`})
            }
            else if (interaction) {
                await interaction.reply({content: `>  Pinging..`});
                interaction.editReply({content: `>  Pong! Latency: **${client.ws.ping}ms**`});
            }
        }

} as ICommand
```

**potential cause, but i no longer receive this error even though I couldn't find a fix.**

> throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request); ^
> DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction

Full discord bot code can be found on my GitHub {as i cant fit it here} [here](https://github.com/28Riptide12/Admin-bot).

Comment: Didn't you already ask this?

Comment: yes, but I did it wrong so I just re-did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to put a latency ping
just simply use `Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp` as ping

example:

```js
const ping = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp
```

then use `ping` variable anywhere you want to put

Comment: my ping command works its just the other commands.

Comment: oh okay, great. hope you find the solution